# Why isn't my compute shader doing anything?

Tags: c#, opengl, textures, compute-shader

I'm in OpenGL 4.5 (OpenGL.net in c#, but the code is very similar to normal OpenGL code), and am trying to use a compute shader. Here's what I have so far:

```
// (Compile and link stuff, this part I know works)

// Use the compute shader
Gl.UseProgram(program);

// Create the texture the compute shader will output to
int textureWidth = 512, textureHeight = 512;
uint[] texturesMaking = new uint[1];
Gl.GenTextures(texturesMaking);
uint texture = texturesMaking[0];
Gl.ActiveTexture(Gl.TEXTURE0);
Gl.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2d, texture);
Gl.TextureParameter(Gl.TEXTURE_2D, Gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.NEAREST);
Gl.TextureParameter(Gl.TEXTURE_2D, Gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.NEAREST);
Gl.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2d, 0, Gl.RGBA32F, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.Float, IntPtr.Zero);

// Get the shader output variable and set it
int location = Gl.GetUniformLocation(program, "destTex");
Gl.Uniform1(location, texture); 
Gl.BindImageTexture(0, texture, 0, false, 0, Gl.READ_WRITE, Gl.RGBA32F);

// Send off the compute shader to do work, with one group per pixel
//  (I know this is far less than optimal, it was just a debugging thing)
Gl.DispatchCompute((uint)textureWidth, (uint)textureHeight, 1);

// Wait for compute shader to finish
Gl.MemoryBarrier(Gl.SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);

// Looking at the texture, it is black
```

And here is my compute shader:

```
#version 450
layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;
layout(rgba32f) uniform image2D destTex;

void main () {
  imageStore (destTex, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0));
}
```

If I understand this correctly, my texture should be a purple/pink color after the shader runs, but instead it is just black, and printing out a few of the pixels' colors shows that all the values are zero as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you "Looking at the texture"? Do you have a memory barrier that matches the kind of "looking" you're doing?

Comment: Ah, that might be the issue. I'm using `Gl.GetTexImage(TextureTarget.Texture2d, 0, PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.Float, pixelArrayPointer);` (for a pointer to a `float[]` of size `textureWidth*textureHeight*4`). Then once I have that float data, I save it to a image, then open that image to see the contents.

Comment: For those that are interested I put my resulting code [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1205676/view.html)

Comment: You do not need to pin *pixelArrayPointer* if you use the *object* overload version. The object can be any Array instance or value type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in how you tell the shader which texture to use. The value set by

```
int location = Gl.GetUniformLocation(program, "destTex");
Gl.Uniform1(location, texture);
```

has to be the image texture unit (the first parameter of the `Gl.BindImageTexture` command), not the texture itself. Since you are using the image texture unit 0, you also have to pass 0 to the uniform:

```
GLuint unit = 0;
int location = Gl.GetUniformLocation(program, "destTex");
Gl.Uniform1(location, unit); 
Gl.BindImageTexture(unit, texture, 0, false, 0, Gl.READ_WRITE, Gl.RGBA32F);
```

Comment: Alternatively, just set the uniform location from the shader. He's using a CS, so he must have GL 4.30, so he can do that.